# Can `consteval` delegating constructor be called from an ordinary constructor?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, consteval

In the following struct definition, the constructor `A(int)` delegates its work to immediate-function constructor `A()`:

```
struct A {       
    int i = 0;
    consteval A() = default;
    A(int) : A() {}
};
```

Clang accepts it, but not GCC complaining:

```
error: 'this' is not a constant expression
```

and MSVC:

```
'A::A': call to immediate function is not a constant expression
```

Demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/7e3fWzYzr

Which compiler is correct?

Comment: Without the member variable `i` GCC is happy too, fwiw. Even making `i` `static` seems to make GCC happy.

Comment: As far as I understand it any consteval function will not result in a runtime callable function. And the compilers that reject the code are correct.

Comment: Mmm.. but why can't the compiler generate a run-time available constructor `A(int)` that uses the compile-time known constructor `A()`? Plus, see my comment above.

Comment: You can also appease GCC by removing the default member initializer. As it stands, this is asking an immediate function to fiddle with a run-time entity.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica, but why would the presence of a member variable such as `i` influence this, given it is not even used by either ctor?

Comment: @Enlico - Of course it's used. The c'tor does the actual initialization.

Comment: Hmm, still getting my head around this I still think clang is a bit too lenient : https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/5v7Pjo7G4

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica, true, silly me.

Answer (score 1):

I think such non-constexpr constructor should be accepted, as gcc has already been accepting the following code.

```
struct Foo {
    int a = 0;
    
    consteval Foo() = default;
    
    static consteval Foo make_foo() noexcept { return Foo{}; }
    
    // Foo(iny) : Foo() {}
    Foo(int) : Foo(make_foo()) {}
};

int main()
{
    static_cast<void>(Foo{42});
}
```

I guess this is also a bug in the C++ standard, seems tracked by the issue [CWG2410](https://wg21.link/cwg2410).

IMO currently consteval constructor calls are not specified correctly, because in C++ a constructor call is never itself an expression, and hence shouldn't be considered as a constant expression.

Comment: Thanks. To make your example closer to the one in the question, one can write `A(int) : A(A()) {}`, which is indeed accepted by GCC: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/v8Ta3zYKr

Answer (score 0):

As you know, `this` is a parameter to all non-static member functions. And parameters are never constant expressions. So `this` can't be used in a constant expression.

When you initialize the non-static member variable like:

```
int i = 0;
```

this initialization will take place at **run-time**. And don't think that your empty (`defaulted`) constructor is doing nothing. It actually will have to initialize `i` with zero at run-time. But how is the compiler supposed to generate a `consteval` function (like your default ctor) which does run-time tasks?! It's just a contradiction.

Let me show you a similar scenario:

```
consteval int multiply( const int op1, const int op2 )
{
    return op1 * op2;
}

int main( )
{
    constexpr int op1 { 2 };
    constexpr int op2 { 3 };
    std::cout << multiply( op1, op2 ) << '\n'; // compiles for obvious reasons

    int op3 { 2 };
    int op4 { 3 };
    std::cout << multiply( op3, op4 ) << '\n'; // doesn't compile
}
```

And:

```
test.cpp: In function 'int main()':
test.cpp:57:32: error: the value of 'op3' is not usable in a constant expression
   57 |         std::cout << multiply( op3, op4 ) << '\n';
      |                                ^~~
test.cpp:55:13: note: 'int op3' is not const
   55 |         int op3 { 2 };
      |             ^~~
```

In the 1st call, the `consteval` function is receiving `constexpr` arguments. So it's happy.
In the 2nd call, it's receiving non-`constexpr` arguments.
`this` for your `consteval` ctor causes a similiar condition:

```
test.cpp: In constructor 'A::A(int)':
test.cpp:41:22: error: 'this' is not a constant expression
   41 |         A( int ) : A() { }
      |                      ^
```

Comment: Can you make `this` a constant expression similar to `op1` and `op2` - by declaring `constexpr A a {}`?

Comment: @Sebastian Yes, it's possible. But it won't solve the OP's issue. The problem with `this` will still be there.